# Getting data in Console but cant display in angular

Tags: node.js, angular6

**This is mine products.component.ts and mine Json response on Node server and Angular server but i am not able to render it on my product.component.html**

```
constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log('Hello fellow user');
    this.getProducts();
    this.getData();
   }


  getData(){
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
      .pipe(map((res:Response)=>res.json()))

    // return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
    //   map(this.extractData),
    //   catchError(this.handleError));
  }
getProducts(){
  this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.data=data;
  })
}
```

**This is mine html of product component**

```
<p>Products work</p>
<div class="container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data.products">
    <h2>{{product.id}}</h2>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**This is mine res.json*[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]*
[image]

Comment: what is your data var?

Comment: private apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/admin/products";
  data:any ={};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should declare your `data` as array, as typed array if you have Product class:

```
data: Product[] = [];
```

Then I think you are wrong referring you data because into component class you assign

```
this.data=data;
```

the in your template you try to access with

```
data.products
```

Try changing *ngFor line with this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of data">
```

Comment: let me try bro!!

Comment: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: It means that you are binding ngfor to a variable that is not an array. You should assure that returned data is an array of product. If it is an Object containing an array of Product you must match that array.